# Querying Windows Update Errors using PowerShell Get-WinEvent or Get-WMIObject

Tags: powershell, event-handling, event-log, error-log, get-winevent

Trying to create a simple Windows Update error query using Get-WinEvent (although I would prefer querying a WMI Object for use with SCUP):

```
get-winevent -logname System| Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -eq "Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient"}
```

This seems to work for the most part.  However, it only returns informational events and not errors.  Are these located somewhere else and, if so, how would I query them?  For some background, there is a specific update failure occurring on approximately 10% of Windows 10 machines in my environment (missing assembly file) and I want to target it so that I can deploy a solution.

A solution using Get-WinEvent is fine, though I would prefer using Get-WMIObject if possible.

Comment: UPDATE: Get-WinEvent -Logname "Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational" returns the information I seek. I guess the question now is: Where is this located in WMI (namespace / class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after doing some additional research, I stumbled upon [this website](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004991286-How-to-add-event-log-files-to-the-Win32-NTLogEvent-WMI-class) that sheds some light on the issue I'm running into.  Essentially, while most, if not all Windows Events are logged in the ***C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\logs*** folder, not all Windows Events are replicated in WMI by default.

In PowerShell, **Get-WinEvent** appears to use the above folder when querying its event data, whereas **Get-EventLog** uses the *Win32_WinNTLogEvent* WMI class.

In my original question, I mentioned that I was unable to query Windows Update error events using Get-WinEvent.  This is because I was pointing to the **System** log file, which does not contain the information.  The **Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational** log file (literal path being *C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\logs\Microsoft-Windows-UpdateClient%4Operational.evtx*) does contain this information, so my query can simply be changed up using something similar to the following:

```
Get-WinEvent -logname "Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational" | Where-Object {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq "Error"}
```

In order to query the same data returned by Get-WinEvent using the *Win32_NTLogEvent* WMI class, the registry must first be modified. Again, the link I posted in this answer describes the process in greater detail, but essentially I performed the following registry mod:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational]
"File"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Winevt\\Logs\\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient%4Operational.evtx"
"Primary Module"="Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational"
"Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,\
  00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,\
  65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,77,00,65,00,76,00,74,00,61,00,70,00,69,00,2e,\
  00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
```

**Note:** The "Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational" Expanded String (REG_EXPAND_SZ) at the end there is pointing to ***%SystemRoot%\system32\wevtapi.dll***

Once the registry was modified, I was able to query the error events as follows:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational' AND Type='Error'"
```

Somewhat of a pain considering that Windows Update errors should *probably* be present in the Win32_NTLogEvent WMI class by default (ah, Microsoft).  Still, this essentially resolves my question.

One additional point to mention.  The website above states that, upon editing the registry, you'd be able to query the new events immediately.  I had to reboot my machine first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Win32_NTLogEvent* like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent |?{($_.LogFile -eq 'System') -and ($_.SourceName -eq 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient') }
```

Note: You can further filter with **Type** which will tell you about information or error or warning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This query essentially does what I've already been doing. Doesn't appear to get around the core issue I'm facing, which is that the Events of Type 'Error' in the Microsoft-Windows-UpdateClient' source do not appear in the query.  When I look in the Event Viewer under this log, the errors appear.  When queried in PowerShell, however, they do not.

Comment: @WKJ: Its with wmiobject which you have been requesting upon

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything that actually states this but it looks like `Get-WinEvent` by default only returns information messages. If you want to see the other then you need to tell it to return those. One way to do it is with `-FilterHashtable`.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='System';Level=1,2}
```

That would return only warnings and error.

1 - Error

2 - Warning

4 - Information

You can look at the enum `[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]` to see where I got the numbers from.

[Looking at MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1) you can see what the hashtable filter supports..

```
LogName=<String[]>
ProviderName=<String[]>
Path=<String[]>
Keywords=<Long[]>
ID=<Int32[]>
Level=<Int32[]>
StartTime=<DateTime>
EndTime=<DataTime>
UserID=<SID>
Data=<String[]>
*=<String[]>
```

If your WMI queries are having similar issues then you can do something like this

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NTLogEvent -filter "(logfile='Application') AND (type='error')"
```

You can find some tangential examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Write a WMI query (this overrides weird event type filters):

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent" |?{(($_.LogFile -eq 'System') -and ($_.Type -in ("Error", "Warning"))) -and ($_.SourceName -eq 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient') }
```